# mobile number issue when sending post request to register

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, swift5, urlsession

Here is the problem when I click to the button it gives me response from server saying Mobile number is not valid I think because phone number must include + which refers to the key of the country and I don't know if my body in the code support (+) or not

---

Note the body from the server, it should be like that

```
"username": "asik-tech1s22ss22",
  "accountType": "Individual",
  "name": "asik-tech",
  "mobile": "+201227823311",
  "password": "asik2020",
  "password_confirmation": "asik2020",
  "gender": "Female",
  "email": "admin122@wasik-tessch.codm2",
  "country": "Egypt"
```

---

My Code :

```
@IBAction func formNextButton_clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let url = URL(string: "http://18.224.184.27:7000/api/v1/users/root-create")!
        let body = "email=\(companyEmailField.text!.lowercased())&name=\(companyNameField.text!.lowercased())&username=\(userNameField.text!.lowercased())&password=\(passwordField.text!)&password_confirmation=\(confirmPasswordField.text!)&country=\(countryField.text!)&mobile=\(phoneNumberField.text!)&gender=\(genderField.text!)&accountType=\(sender.tag)"
        print(body)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // STEP 2. Execute created above request
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            // access helper class
            let helper = Helper()
            
            // error
            if error != nil {
                helper.showAlert(title: "Server Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                return
            }
            
            // fetch JSON if no error
            do {
                
                // save mode of casting data
                guard let data = data else {
                    helper.showAlert(title: "Data Error", message: error!.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    return
                }
                
                // fetching all JSON received from the server
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                
                print(json as Any)
                
            // error while fetching JSON
            } catch {
                helper.showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
                
                
            }
            
            
        }.resume()
        
        
    }
```

Comment: That's strange, because the format of your param seems to be JSON (missing opening and closing brackets), but you are using url encoding parameter. Is that correct?

Comment: @Larme ofcaurse I'm using the params of the url here is the response : my printed body and response :

email=abdallahco@yahoo.com&name=abdallahco&username=abdallahuser&password=123456&password_confirmation=123456&country=Egypt&mobile=+201094339599&gender=Male&accountType=2
Optional({
    error =     {
        message = "Mobile number is not valid ";
        status = 400;
    };
})

Comment: Maybe server just don't accept mobile number in that format? Have you tried sending without "+" or without the whole prefix "+20"?

Comment: the mobile num in the server is string and accept these formats and I've tried without "+" or without the whole prefix "+20" like you said and still the error message appears Mobile number is not valid

Comment: The format of the data at the start of your question (almost json) and the format you are sending (body containing a query string) are different.  Can you confirm what your server expects? Have you tried with something like postman?  For a query string you,would need to percent encode the + sign.

Comment: Try with by replacing the "+" with `%2b`. Does it works? Yes? BUT I'd still check that the format should be JSON over url encoded (easier), and that I guess that if you have 2 names, imagine a family name composed of 2 words, you'll also have the issue because you didn't percent escaped the space. Else, ULRQueryItem should be helpful to not construct the param manually.